# Using ul Inside ol

Tags: html, javadoc

I'm trying to write a valid HTML however this fails:

```
<ol>   
<li>First</li>   
<li>Second</li>
<ul>
  <li>First of second</li>
</ul>
</ol>
```

This fails at when generating javadoc. It says:

```
error: tag not allowed here: <ul>
```

Desired output should be like that:

1. First
2. Second
  - First of second

Isn't it valid to define ul inside ol?

Comment: You didn't add the `li` tag. Add `li` tag and inside add the `ul`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `ul` in an `li`, as the only valid children of `ul` and `ol` are `li`.

If you don't want the bullet to show, you can exclude them via a class

HTML:

```
<ol>   
  <li>First</li>   
  <li>Second</li>
  <li class="no-bullet">
    <ul>
      <li>First of second</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
.no-bullet {
  list-style: none;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71p7cvsz/)

If you don't want to use CSS, either use inline-styles or the `type` attribute:

```
<li style="list-style: none;">Item</li>
```

OR

```
<li type="none">Item</li>
```

Comment: It puts a number in front of the first of second. I don't want it.

Comment: I should do it with pure HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Place the unordered list `ul` inside the list item `li`,

```
<ol>   
<li>First</li>   
<li>Second
  <ul>
    <li>First of second</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sq8dhs4d/)